# Nginx 404 error when navigation from main / home page to another one (Rails 5, AWS EC2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am getting this error when navigating to a linked page in the main page of my app.

I am using Nginx and Passenger

In the `application/_header.html.erb` file I have this line for thelink:

`<li><%= link_to 'Comments', comments_path, method: "get" %></li>`

for which in the `routes.rb` I have:

  `root to: "application#index"
  resources :comments`

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/ubuntu/test-aws-deploy-with-git-ec2-rds/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name ec2-54-173-78-253.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Don't know why I can't navigate in this app between pages?
Do I need to specify somewhere any page this app will use?

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to comment below line from your /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
  location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Its work I also faced same problem.